# How to use index match (array formula) to return corresponding values from a drop down list?

Tags: arrays, excel, list

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLfy.png)

[Excel Screenshot with Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFdIZ.png)

I have attached photos to show an idea of what I am trying to do. Basically, I have a very large list of features that are shared between certain groups. I want to use a drop down list of the features, and then have a formula that will output the group that has the lowest cost of that feature along with the cost of that feature within the group.

(Also you will see that I purposefully ignore zero values. I do this because not every group has a certain feature and those cells default to zero).

I figured out how to get the cost of the feature to output, but I'm having trouble getting to output the group name. I am assuming there will be an array formula to do this, but I am just starting to learn those and I'm having trouble with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could always use the same approach you used to pull in the value, by pulling in the index of the column heading that matches the computed min, and using an offset function to match on the right row:

```
=+INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH($B$10,OFFSET($B$1:$D$1,MATCH($A$7,$A$2:$A$4,0),0),0))
```

The thing is, I'm not sure how you would want to handle ties, if 2 vendors had the same price, this would match the first one in the list.

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely work for now. If I was going to try to account for ties in the future, do you have any recommendations on where I should start my search?